# I am having problem in populating dropdown list which has its data referenced in different model in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

MenuItems model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using TruYum.Models;

namespace TruYum.Models
{
    public class MenuItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Price { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Free Delivery")]
        [Required]
        public bool FreeDelivery { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date Of Launch")]
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Category")]
        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Category Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Web.Mvc;


namespace TruYum.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    
    }

}
```

I have to make a menu items form from MenuItems model in which I have to create a dropdown list with html helper and populate it with the Names from Category Model given is that Categoryid in category is foreign key referenced with category id in menuitems model.

I am using asp.net web application template
plz help I am a beginner in asp.net!!
Please assume that I have already build Dbcontext class and have a row entered or hardcoded manually in Categories table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should add the Category class as a property in the MenuItem.

```
public class MenuItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Free Delivery")]
    [Required]
    public bool FreeDelivery { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Of Launch")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))]
    public Category Category {get; set;}

}
```

After that, if you're using the entity framework, in the controller where you get the menuItem data, you should include the category class. Something like this:

```
var model = context.MenuItems.Include(m => m.Category).toList();
```